# Selecting xpath input given label

Tags: python, xpath, selenium-webdriver

So I normally use `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id=(//*[contains(text(), "User Name")]/@for)]')` to enter information into text boxes, but this hasn't been working for the following code:

```
<div class="form-group text-entry required ">
  <div class="label-set" id="answerTextBox-30918642">Primary User Name (First and Last Name)</div>
  <div class="group-set" role="group" aria-labelledby="answerTextBox-30918642">
    <input id="pageResponse_Responses_Index" name="pageResponse.Responses.Index" type="hidden" value="fta30918642">
    <input class="freeTextAnswerId form-control" id="pageResponse_Responses_fta30918642__FreeTextAnswerId" name="pageResponse.Responses[fta30918642].FreeTextAnswerId" type="hidden" value="30918642">
    <label for="answerTextBox-30918642-free" class="sr-only">Write-In Answer</label>
    <input class="form-control free-text" id="answerTextBox-30918642-free" name="pageResponse.Responses[fta30918642].FreeText" type="text" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried messing with the xpath to select the input,

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(.,'User Name')]/following-sibling::input[1]")
```

but so far nothing I've tried so far has worked correctly. This works to find the element containing the label, `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'User Name')]")`, but my issue is then selecting the input to send keys to.

Comment: //div//input[@class='form-control free-text'] Does this work for you?

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: @JeffC Does this help

Comment: @Jake Some... I fixed it. I generally use an HTML beautifier like https://www.cleancss.com/html-beautify/ when I post HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your XPath to

```
//div[contains(.,'User Name')]/following::input[@type='text']
```

The [`following` axis from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following).

> The `following` axis indicates all the nodes that appear after the context node, except any `descendant`, `attribute`, and `namespace` nodes.

The other `INPUT`s are hidden so specifying `@type='text'` will find only the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to get it working integration Santhosh's suggestion:

`//*[contains(text(), \"User Name\")]/../div//input[@class='form-control free-text']`